# Where is package-lock.json reading version from?

Tags: reactjs, npm

In my app I have the following `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "versionCode": 2,
  "main": "./src/App.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest",
    "coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "format": "prettier --write ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // lots of stuff here
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // lots of other stuff here
  },
  "private": true,
  "jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setup.js"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I `rm -rf node_modules`, then `rm -rf package-lock.json`, and then run `npm install`, it succeeds, but generates the following `package-lock.json`:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 3,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "myapp",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "dependencies": {
        // lots of stuff here
      }
    // lots of other stuff here
  }
}
```

Why is `package-lock.json` showing a `version` of "1.0.0", instead of "1.0.2"? Where could it be reading that version from?

Besides the node_modules and existing package-lock.json file, what else could I try culling out so that the correct version number gets picked up?

Comment: `npm install` reads the version from `package.json`. So either you haven't saved your file to disk before installing or you are installing from in a different directory from a different package.json

Comment: Right, thats exactly my question! I can confirm `package.json` has been saved to disk (I actually pulled it from GitHub where the code also shows `version` as "1.0.2". So how could I trace where `package-lock.json` is getting "1.0.0" from?

Comment: All `npm ...` commands search for the respective `package.json` either in the current working directory and if none is found it goes up the path until it finds a package.json in the parent directory. But I can't think of any situation, where a `package-lock.json` is newly created and contains a different version number than the `package.json` residing in the same directory

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It reads the version from `package.json`.

Here is a link to the npm docs regarding your question:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-lock-json#file-format

Snippet:

### File Format

`name`

The name of the package this is a package-lock for. This will match what's in `package.json`.

`version`

The version of the package this is a package-lock for. This will match what's in `package.json`.

`lockfileVersion`

An integer version, starting at `1` with the version number of this document whose semantics were used when generating this `package-lock.json`.

Note that the file format changed significantly in npm v7 to track information that would have otherwise required looking in `node_modules` or the npm registry. Lockfiles generated by npm v7 will contain `lockfileVersion: 2`.

No version provided: an "ancient" shrinkwrap file from a version of npm prior to npm v5.
`1`: The lockfile version used by npm v5 and v6.
`2`: The lockfile version used by npm v7 and v8. Backwards compatible to v1 lockfiles.
`3`: The lockfile version used by npm v9 and above. Backwards compatible to npm v7.
npm will always attempt to get whatever data it can out of a lockfile, even if it is not a version that it was designed to support.